# How can I add like a textbox with longer text to a chart in vega-lite?

Tags: visualization, vega-lite

I have an Scatterplot with a second layer for two lines with benchmark-data, now I need like a legend for these lines. I already managed to include them to the legend of the Scatterplot, but that does not help, as the legends name does not fit for these additional lines and especially the despriction is too long, to be displayed as a legend entry.

What I have is this (the lowest two points in the legend):
[Only two words for description in legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xpmfu.png)

And what I need is this:

[colored textboxes with description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdYqn.png)

```
   const spec = {
    ...sharedChartSpec,
    height: 350,
    config: {
        axis: {
            tickColor: 'lightgrey',
            titleFontSize: 15,
            grid:false
        },
        style: {
            cell: {
                stroke: "transparent"
            }
        },
    },
    // title: {text: "Spezifischer Energieverbrauch [kWh/m2]", align: "center"},
    layer: [
       {
            data: {name: 'values'}, // note: vega-lite data attribute is a plain object instead of an array,
            mark: {type: 'circle', size: 20, opacity: 1},
            encoding: {
                x: {field: 'constructionYear', type: 'temporal', timeUnit: 'year', axis: {title: ''}, "scale": {"domain": [1880,2022]}},
                y: {field: 'consumption_perm2', type: 'quantitative', axis: {title: null}, "scale": {"domain": [0, 350]}},
                color: {field: 'heater', type: 'nominal', scale: customScale, title: 'Energieträger'},
                opacity: {condition: {param: "Heater", value: 1},
                    value: 0.2},
                tooltip: [
                    {field: "address", type: "nominal", title:'Adresse', fontSize:5},
                    {field: "town", type: "nominal", title:'Ort'},
                    {field: "heater", type: "nominal", title:'Primärer Energieträger'},
                    {field: "consumption_perm2", type: "quantitative", title:'Verbrauch in kWh/m2'},
                    {field: "EEK", type: "nominal", title:'EEK'}
                ]
            },

            params: [
                {
                    "name": "grid",
                    "select": "interval",
                    "bind": "scales"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Heater",
                    "select": {"type": "point", "fields": ["heater"]},
                    "bind": "legend"
                }
            ],
       },
       {
            data: {name: 'benchmark'},
            mark: {type: 'line'},
            encoding: {
                x: {field: 'constructionYear', type: 'temporal', timeUnit: 'year', axis: {title: null}},
                y: {field: 'consumption_perm2', type: 'quantitative', axis: {title: null}},
                color: {field: 'typ', type: 'nominal', scale: customScale},
        }
        },
        {
            data: {name: 'demand'},
            mark: {type: 'line'},
            encoding: {
                x: {field: 'constructionYear', type: 'temporal', timeUnit: 'year', axis: {title: null}},
                y: {field: 'consumption_perm2', type: 'quantitative', axis: {title: null}},
                color: {field: 'typ', type: 'nominal', scale: customScale},
            },
        }
       ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place your text wherever you want using dx and dy properties.
[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "Google's stock price over time.",
  "data": {"url": "data/stocks.csv"},
  "transform": [{"filter": "datum.symbol==='GOOG'"}],
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "line",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "date", "type": "temporal"},
        "y": {"field": "price", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    },
    {
      "data": {"values": [{}]},
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "align": "left",
        "baseline": "bottom",
        "text": ["Line 1", "Line 2"],
        "dx": 150,
        "dy": -50
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you again! It does not solve my problem completely, as for my case, it is not possible to place the text outside the graph, because of the interval selection function. So my plot does not have an ending as you can zoom and drag until infinity. But your answer gives me another option to solve my problem. Thanks a lot for fast responding!

Answer (score 2):

I can't reuse your code but here is an example of multiline annotation which you should be able to build on.

[Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AHE2bMoLgByCAAIImNlADWlnJqhxLbUuss6EcSopUkTBRUUAZ1QTRA4M5bBwhKKAhiEABfJUx1JFkIADM2dQQ0AG1QXJpBTDh1KOUghgRKCABPBCY2QQBebrN9AHk+-TM0gF0lQSRm6pLQZHV7KOFZOAC4WSg2ZRpZMjRQAA89kHK4QWVaoJWM5pwV9CqEHAKkSPSQZqOTs6jnGlcAzA3O4gACODGyOmCOlIaVS6VAaw2Wx2R0OoRASDIZHUfCqUWQhyUX3O6DqeOutyiDyeWVeSg+6Mx2Nxd1ASHUZAJFzxb2JPxcVxAgMp6DBELoQRoMLhSjmC3RwuBVX2mACLxoZD0IFMuVVSiYSAgp22wPa2DYRQycBVJRAABkTZYAIwBB3LSwAJhAIzhPqAA)

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "Google's stock price over time.",
  "data": {"url": "data/stocks.csv"},
  "transform": [{"filter": "datum.symbol==='GOOG'"}],
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "line",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "date", "type": "temporal"},
        "y": {"field": "price", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    },
    {
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"aggregate": "max", "field": "date", "type": "temporal"},
        "y": {
          "aggregate": {"argmax": "date"},
          "field": "price",
          "type": "quantitative"
        }
      },
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "align": "left",
        "baseline": "bottom",
        "text": ["Line 1", "Line 2"]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot your for your answer so far. The problem is, that I included (and need) the possibility to zoom in and out into my data points. With this function, the text at the end of the line disappears, that's why I would like to have it outside of the plot itself, in the region of the legend, which is not effected by zooming.

Comment: I'll add another answer